# Which cloud service should I use for a simple java program?

Tags: cloud-service

I created a program in java that searches for and finds primes numbers. It works very well but I want to have it look for much, much high numbers but my computer isn't all that great. I tried looking at google cloud and AWS but they seem like they're for apps/websites? I'm a bit confused and just wondering what would be best for this project.

Comment: Are you concerned that your program might run slowly, or what?  How slow is too slow?

Comment: Please specify more criteria and describe more your needs and intentions. Also, finish your "much, much" thought.

Comment: Well I want to try and use it to find prime numbers that are thousands of digits long and in two days it got to around 1 quadrillion on my home computer so if I want to reach those numbers anytime soon I need more computing power or multiple machines running my program at the same time

Comment: @SamanthaClark Edit your Question to provide further info rather than post as comments.

Answer (score 1):

## Heroku

Heroku was one of the first and best Java cloud providers. I believe the use Amazon AWS under-the-covers.

## DigitalOcean

DigitalOcean is a cloud VM provider. They can instantly spin up a configured [BSD](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD) ([FreeBSD](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD)) or [Linux](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) virtual machine.

Simple pricing. Very cheap to get started, pay by the hour, less than a U.S. penny per hour.

Excellent documentation and many helpful articles including how to install Java on your VM.

They run their own hardware in multiple data centers. Apparently high quality including all flash-based storage.

Comment: Do you know where I could find information on how these sites work? Like would more CPU's mean they could do the math faster? OR would I have to find a way to split the program among different CPU's (like one looks for numbers between 1-100,000, another looks between 100,000-100,000,000)